# what can i do to solve moodle+wordpress synchronisation?

Tags: wordpress, moodle

I did everything I watched on youtube, followed the steps to connect my WordPress website to moodlewith Edwiser-bridge,still, I have a problem. a user connected to WordPress cannot access moodle even if it is saved in the list of users in moodle.I get this error
"Invalid login, please try again"
any help, please

Comment: On the edwiser-bridge page, its says you need edwiser-pro for the login - is that the version you are using?

https://edwiser.org/bridge/

Comment: okey thanks ,i think this is the problem.